# Find minimum of $a+b$ under the condition $\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}=1$ where $m,n$ are fixed arguments

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analysis, inequality, analytic-geometry

Assume $m,n \in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed. And $a,b(a>b>0)$ satisfied the equation $$\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}=1$$
Find $\min\{a+b\}$

Comment: You need to show your own effort while posting questions - it helps people answer you better, I have noticed you have done so in the past, continuing to do so helps at least avoid negative votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=m\sec t$ and $b=n\csc t$ where $t\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

\begin{align*}
  f(t) &= m\sec t+n\csc t \\
  f'(t) &=m\sec t \tan t-n\csc t \cot t \\ 
\end{align*}

$$f'(t)=0 \implies \frac{n}{m}=\tan^{3} t$$

\begin{align*}
  \min(a+b) &=
  \left(
    \frac{m}{\sqrt[3]{m}}+\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n}}
  \right) \sqrt{m^{2/3}+n^{2/3}} \\
 &= \left( m^{2/3}+n^{2/3} \right)^{3/2}
\end{align*}

The answer let me thinking of the [longest ladder problem](http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/3/applications.2/).

> **Further point to be noticed:**
>
> At $\displaystyle t=\tan^{-1} \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{m}}$,
>
> $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{m}{n} \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{m}}$$
>   $$\frac{a^{3}}{b^{3}}=\frac{m^{2}}{n^{2}} $$
>   $$a>b>0 \implies m^{2}>n^{2}$$
>   When $m^{2}<n^{2}$ and $0<b<a$, $a+b$ will be bounded below by $2\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$ which corresponds to $m\sec t=n\csc t$.

Comment: How do you ensure you have $a> b$?  For e.g. in the case you have graphed (i.e. $m=1, n=8$), can you tell me for what value of $a, b$, you get the minimum you say of $(m^{2/3}+n^{2/3})^{3/2}=3\sqrt3$?

Comment: Honestly, I forgot to impose the constraint of $a>b$.

Comment: The problem is only when $m\le n$, in that case this solution requires $a\le b$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
By Holder's inequality,
$$\left(\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2} \right)(a+b)^2 \geqslant (m^{2/3}+n^{2/3})^3$$

Comment: Note that equality is possible iff $a^3:b^3 = m^2:n^2$, so if $m \le n$, we do not have any minimum (the number cannot be achieved), so we get only a lower bound in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Wlog

$a=m\sec t,b=n\csc t$

$(a+b)^2\ge4ab=\dfrac{4mn}{\sin t\cos t}$

The equality occurs if $a=b$

i.e., if $m\sec t=n\csc t$

$\frac m{\cos t}=\frac n{\sin t}=\pm\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$

Comment: The solution should be somehow related to the **longest ladder problem**.