# $\min$ value of $f(x)=a\sec x+b\csc x\;,$ Where $a,b>0$ and $\displaystyle x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: inequality

> $\min$ value of $f(x)=a\sec x+b\csc x\;,$ Where $a,b>0$ and $\displaystyle x\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Although we can solve it using Derivative Test, But my question is can we solve it using $\bf{cauchy}$

or Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}$ or $\bf{Holder\; Inequality}$

Help required, Thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741842/find-minimum-of-ab-under-the-condition-fracm2a2-fracn2b2-1-wh/1741858#1741858

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p=3/2,q=3$ then $1/p+1/q=1$. Now by Hölder's inequality, 
$$(((a\sec x)^\frac1p)^p+((b\csc x)^\frac1p)^p)^\frac1p(((\cos^2)^\frac1q)^q+((\sin^2 x)^\frac1q)^q)^\frac1q\ge (a\sec x)^\frac1p(\cos^2)^\frac1q)+(b\csc x)^\frac1p)((\sin^2 x)^\frac1q)=a^\frac23+b^\frac23. $$

Indeed there's another approach using physical method (static electrical energy in particular). I'll add it to the answer if I have time.